# Python: Loop through the elif section of an if statement

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I'm relatively new to python, so I'm not even sure if I'm approaching this in the correct way. But I haven't found a good solution anywhere.

In order to avoid very ugly and repetitive code, i want to loop the elif part of the if statement.

This is the ugly code i want to fix:

```
def codeToChar(code):
chars = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"

if code == ord(chars[0]):   ##### SUPER UGLY
    return chars[0]
elif code == ord(chars[1]):
    return chars[1]
elif code == ord(chars[2]):
    return chars[2]
elif code == ord(chars[3]):
    return chars[3]
elif code == ord(chars[4]):
    return chars[4]
elif code == ord(chars[5]):
    return chars[5]
..... etc .....
else:
    return "wat"
```

As you can see, the index is incrementing by one, so I thought looping would be very simple. However, when I tried the following, it didn't work because this must be formulated as an if, elif, elif, else statement, and not many if statements.

My failed attempt:

```
for x in xrange(0,len(chars)-1):
    if code == ord(chars[x]):
        return chars[x]
    else:
        return "wat"
```

How would I go about looping this?
Note: if it's of any relevance, I'm coding this using the curses module, building a keyboard interface for a project.
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for c in chars:
    if code == ord(c):
        return c
return "wat"
```

the second `return` is executed only if no previous `return` has been previously executed (i.e. no character matched).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are just checking whether the code is one of the characters or not. One clean solution would be:

```
c = chr(code)
return c if c in chars else "wat"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a dict:

```
chars = "QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNMqwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
chars_dict = {ord(c): c for c in chars}
return chars_dict.get(code, 'wat')
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't want to return "wat" inside the loop as it'll trigger as soon as the `if` statement fails once. You only want to return an error if *all* iterations failed. Unindent the `else` block to do this.

```
for x in xrange(0,len(chars)-1):
    if code == ord(chars[x]):
        return chars[x]
else:
    return "wat"
```

The `else` block is optional. You could also write:

```
for x in xrange(0,len(chars)-1):
    if code == ord(chars[x]):
        return chars[x]
return "wat"
```

Comment: Could use enumerate rather than xrange over the length